# build-tools folder not found /home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools

Tags: android, kivy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, build-tools

I am making an android app with **python - kivy**.
and using **raspbian - raspberry pi 3**.
trying to use

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

but got the error:

```
# Check that aidl can be executed
# build-tools folder not found 
/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/build-tools
# Search for Aidl
# Aidl not found, please install it.
```

I already have installed Aidl successfully but **the error repeats.**

when trying to install build-tools manually, after commanding

```
~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android
```

I got the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:328)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:316)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:118)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:101)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

any idea??

thank you

Comment: I would really appreciate any help with it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I am only 24 hours in Kubuntu, so my answer might not be perfect but here is all that I could do to fix some of the issues that you have mentioned.

Download build-tools file manually from this website
https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-build-tools.html

Once you have downloaded it, extract it at the /Downloads folder - it makes an android-4.4W folder. Go in Select All and copy

Now go to /home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20 and make a folder named "build-tools" and paste the contents

This will solve the issue of # build-tools folder not found

The next issue will be Aidl not found followed by Aidl didn't start, to fix that do the following:

Now inside that build-tools folder create a new folder and name it 0 - it is zero and capital O. Inside the build-tools folder where you just pasted the contents, there is a file named aidl, copy this file and paste it inside 0. No idea why but this fixes the issue.

Now next issue you will face is, 32 bit issue, followed by Android API 19 issue, and at the end where I gave up was another python related issue. Good luck, hope google can help u.

I am done with Linux/Ubuntu. I will go back to windows and find another way. Linux has too much "conditions" to be met to make things work. Maybe it is beautiful to some advanced level programmer, I find it extremely annoying & unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
It's been a few months since I asked it, so the mean time I just built it in a Ubuntu computer, not rpi. It worked..

I will definitely try your answer next time.

Shahar

Comment: you should consider to use ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

In the buildozer.spec file there is a configuration as android.accept_sdk_license. Set the value as True

android.accept_sdk_license = True

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've solved it by setting the `android.skip_update` to `False` in `buildozer.spec`.

I had it set to `True` because of many tests I did while building for f-droid.

So just switching from:

```
android.skip_update = True
```

to:

```
android.skip_update = False
```

Solved my issue.